# Why did my contract read method call get turned into a transaction using gas fees?

Tags: ethers.js, contract-invocation

I called a contract read method from my React app using ethersjs but it turned into a tx with gas fees.

See the below tx hash on etherscan:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0715c77bbc58b5513421c33c5fd933bcd546ab6cd6b8f2074fde7cb8277d469f

Comment: Can you add your **ethersjs** code into your question body? I think it's probably caused by how you called the `symbol()` function.